# What does $\|u\|^2_2$ mean?

Tags: notation, vectors, normed-spaces, absolute-value

Given a vector $u = (x, y, z)$ what is $\|u\|_2^2$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\| \cdot \|_2$ function is the [$2$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm), i.e. the standard Euclidean length of a vector. Thus,
$$\|(x, y, z)\|_2^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2.$$